# converting C code to MIPS Assembly Language with arrays

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, mips

Ok, so I have to convert the following C code segment to MIPS Assembly.

f = k + A[5]

The question tells me that f is stored in register $s3, k is in $s2 and the base address of array A is $s4. This is what I put as my answer:

add $s3, $s2, $s4

Is this correct? Do I have to do anything special with the 5 in the array? I'm very new to MIPS, so any and all help if VERY much appreciated.

Comment: "converting C code to MIPS" - [An entire family of computer programs is designated to that task.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)

Answer (score 1):

Are you working on this for homework?  If so, are you actually writing out an executable program or just responding to a list of questions?

Either way yes, you do need to account for the 5 in the array.  The question is telling you that `$s4` points to the **base address** of the array, not the 5th index.

*hint: A[0] would be at the same address as the base of the array.*

Comment: @wazy thanks for the heads up.  I noticed nothing came up when I went searching to retag, but didn't find anything.  Is there a new tag for homework type questions or does SO condone just giving away hw answers these days?

Comment: For anyone interested, I found [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812) on meta.  Indeed the `homework` tag has been deprecated.  Editing my response to more politely ask if the question is homework, but still only guiding towards correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. (Off the top of my head). Remember each index is * 4.

```
li $t2, 6            # init 6 to $t2
addi $t2, $t2, $t2   # $t2 * 2
addi $t2, $t2, $t2   # $t2 * 2
addi $t1, $t2, $s4   # A[6 * 4] 
lw $t4, 0($t1)       # load A[6] int $t4
addi $s3, $s2, $t4   # obtain f
```